# Power BI increment page number in URL

Tags: powerbi

Currently in my example only load data from page 0. I have total 5 pages.

How increment page number and load all data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate using a function:

```
    let 
          FnGetOnePage = (pageNo) =>
            let
              Source = Web.Contents("replace with your url", 
                                    [RelativePath="?page=" & Number.ToText(pageNo)]),
             JsonProductResponse = Json.Document(Source ,1252)
          in
             JsonProductResponse,

        GeneratedList =
          List.Generate(
           ()=>[i=1,res = FnGetOnePage(i)],
            each List.IsEmpty([res]) <> true, 
            each [i=[i]+1,res=FnGetOnePage(i)]
        )
    in
        GeneratedList
```

Comment: What is "1252" in your function?

Comment: @Pointer It is encoding value, you can leave it as is or even omit it since it is an optinal parameter in Json.Document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/json-document

Comment: @PratikBhavsar Tnx for answer, but after use your code get https://ibb.co/GQyJn3f  where is define pageNo?

Comment: @user_odoo sorry about the silly mistake, it should look like Source = Web.Contents("replace with your url", 
                                    [RelativePath="?page=" & Number.ToText(pageNo)]),

Comment: @PratikBhavsar  Now add right slash automaticly in function I don't have https://ibb.co/M7TfkGs

Comment: @user_odoo move PowerBITest to the relative path as well [RelativePath="/PowerBITest?page=" & Number.ToText(pageNo)]

Comment: @PratikBhavsar  Yes that is changed but now Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194366/discussion-between-pratik-bhavsar-and-user-odoo).